# Example of continuous function on a closed unit ball with no minimum point at its sphere

Tags: analysis

Find a continuous function f from a closed unit ball $\subset R^2$ -> $R^2$ that is continuously differentiable on the unit ball (B(0,1)), but 0 is not in the range of f. and there is no point $X_0$ at S(0,1) with ||f($x_0$)||=min{||f(y)|| | y $\in$ $\overline B(0,1)$ }

please give some hints without direct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the min/max value theorem. The sphere is a compact region of $\mathbb{R^2}$ and f a continuous function. What does that mean about the values of f on the sphere?

Comment: this means that f must contain a max and a min within the close ball. since Xmin is not on the sphere of the ball, this means that the function that I am looking for must be onto, but I am not sure why can't 0 be the image of a function.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant that the sphere had a min. Consider a function that takes the magnitude of the vector and adds a constant.

Comment: will function f(x, y)=(x*log ($\sqrt{x^2+y^2} $)+1, y*log ($\sqrt{x^2+y^2} $)+1 ) work?

Comment: Possibly. I was thinking something more simple (and I am probably not completely understanding the question). Consider $f(x, y)=(x^2+y^2+1, 0)$.